# Can a program adopt the permissions of the user, or is it completely restricted by owner?

Tags: linux, unix

For example when a program is run in a *nix environment by root user, but the program owner is a non-root user, could that program carry out actions with root privileges?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions of an application are determined on the user that executed the program.

If it would take the permissions of the owner, the `sudo` command, for example, would not have any effect.
Furthermore, most applications in `/bin` (or any other system location) are owned by the root user (so one is not able to (easily) modify them), but are still executed with the users permissions.

Note, that if an program has the [`setuid` or `setgid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit(s) set, then the application is started with respectively the user and/or group permissions.
This allows regular users to perform actions that typically require root permissions without having access to the root account.

To set the `setuid` bit use:

```
chmod u+s /path/to/application
```

Same goes for the `setgid` bit, but using `g+s` instead of `u+s`.

Answer (score 2):

By default the process runs **with the ID and privileges of the user that starts it**, not with the program owner ID. So if `root` starts a process from a program owned by an ordinary user, that process will run with ID=0.

As `Johnsyweb` mentions in the comments, if the program happens to have the `setuid` bit set, it will be run as the owner. That's what `setuid` means: *set user ID*. Typically this is done to allow regular users to run programs such as `ping` that require superuser permissions.

Note however that Linux for example has a superior mechanism in the form of "*Linux Capabilities*" where certain select permissions can be granted instead of full setuid.

Comment: By default, yes. ...unless the executable has the `setuid` attribute set.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Good call. I hoped nobody would mention it :-))

Answer (score 1):

The user starting the program determines the permissions for that run. If you want a program run with the permissions of another user you can either use `su` or `sudo` or set the `setuid` bit for the program

```
chown user program
chmod u+s program
```

This will force the permissions to be used for `user`, no matter who runs the program.